# How to fix 'NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.defaultNumHeapArena() on EMR'

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am new to EMR & Spark. I wrote a simple spark job program in java and build a fat jar. I SSH into EMR cluster and ran that program using 'java -jar mySampleEMRJob.jar'. It ran as per expected.

However, when I ran the same program using /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar mySampleEMRJob.jar, I got error of:

```
 NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.defaultNumHeapArena()
```

The error is shown in the stack trace below.

Now my question is:

1) Why JAVA -jar option is succceeding on same EMR cluster but hadoop jar is failing?

2) How to solve this netty issue.

```
19/05/31 06:44:02 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.2
19/05/31 06:44:02 INFO spark.SparkContext: Submitted application:   SparkJob
19/05/31 06:44:03 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoop
19/05/31 06:44:03 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoop
19/05/31 06:44:03 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
19/05/31 06:44:03 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
19/05/31 06:44:03 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with modify permissions: Set()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.defaultNumHeapArena()I
at org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyUtils.createPooledByteBufAllocator(NettyUtils.java:113)
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.<init>(TransportClientFactory.java:106)
at org.apache.spark.network.TransportContext.createClientFactory(TransportContext.java:99)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.<init>(NettyRpcEnv.scala:71)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnvFactory.create(NettyRpcEnv.scala:461)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:249)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:175)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:424)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:926)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
at SparkJob.main(SparkJob.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when using AWS Pipeline to run a Spark application on an EMR cluster.

As your code is also using Spark, it's important that you use `spark-submit` to execute jar.

E.g.

```
spark-submit --class com.company.acme.Main s3://mybucket/emr/sparkapp.jar
```

Otherwise, if you run the jar directly, the wrong classpath is used which does not contain the correct version of the dependant jars.